# How can I get Cordova to embed a custom iOS framework automatically via a plugin?

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

According to [this bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10034), custom iOS Frameworks are added automatically to Xcode's 'Embed Binaries' section.

The 'offending' code linked to from that bug report (the code I actually need) is also present in the version of Cordova I'm using (version 6.0.0, via Meteor), but the framework is still added is a non-embedded binary, making my app fail on startup.

So I'm wondering how I can ensure my custom frameworks get embedded?

The code in question looks like this (in my plugin.xml):

```
<platform name="ios">
    <framework src="build/MyFramework.framework" custom="true" />
</platform>
```

Comment: did you able to solve it and how plz ?

Comment: @SyraKozZ unfortunately not. We are just removing the custom framework from the list of linked Frameworks and adding it to the list of embedded ones by hand after building

Comment: tx, i build it from the xcode only and its works

Comment: @ephemer : The custom framework you use is built with Swift?

Comment: @GJDK yes. This question is over two years old and we are no longer using Cordova, but apparently it's still not fixed :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the new 'embed' option that is mentioned in the jira ticket to see if they are available in your cordova version.

```
<platform name="ios">
    <framework src="build/MyFramework.framework" custom="true" embed="true"/>
</platform>
```

Maybe the default value for embed is false.